# Can I send parameters to the controller's action in Kohana?

Tags: php, routes, kohana

Shouldn't I? Is it considered bad practice? If so, why?

For ex:

```
    public function action_index($err='', $success='')
    {
        $priorities = Model::factory('Priorities')->get_all();
        $this->template->content = View::factory("admin/priorities/list.tpl", array('rows' => $priorities, 'error' => $err));
    }
```

**UPD:**
Why do I ask? [Controller Parameters deprecated](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/8454/controller-parameters-deprecated-in-3-1/p1) in one framework

Comment: Yes you can  pass parameters via controller

Comment: Since most PHP MVC frameworks determine the controller and action from the URL, using a single piece of routing code, they can't really do something different for each individual controller::action - e.g. passing different arguments... but the arguments are generally just REQUEST vars of one kind or another anyway, so you can just retrieve them inside the action.

Comment: the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [**the documentation**](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/guide/kohana/mvc/controllers.md#parameters), the answer is: no.
Instead you should be using `$this->request` within the "controller" to access the user input.

As for "what data is contained there", you should consult the code for the instantiation of `Request`, that can be found [here](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Request.php).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can pass it. i'm doing it in CODEIGNITER.